# Can I use "come over" for going to someone's place?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

For example, if I wanna go to my friend's place tomorrow. Can I ask him: "hey I can come over to your place tomorrow"?

It seems like ***come over*** can only be used when you want someone to come to your own place. Like "hey man you can come over to my house whenever you want." So I just wanna ask for a way to say "going to someone's place".

Comment: Also, a minor change, it should be "Hey, can I come over..."

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh Yes. "I can come over" is a statement -- I can. "Can I come over" is a question, presumably asking for permission.

Comment: Yes, my suggestion would be correct if the author is asking it, not stating it. The author had used the words "Can I ask him: ", hence the suggestion of rearrangement in the first place.

Comment: You can come over and go over to someone's house and in the UK, you might pop over and pop round.

Answer (score 1):

To use the statement “come over”, either the speaker’s or the listener’s location must be the topic of discussion. Another third location would not work.

Comment: For the OP, perhaps make it clear that you mean "yes" to his question

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Idiomatically, at least, "can I come over to your place" is commonly said and understood. One could argue that it should be "go over", but it's not.